# Using google places api with jQuery autocomplete

Tags: api, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using google places and jquery to achieve the goal of once the user starts typing in an input field, it does a call to google places and feeds the results in a dropdown (via jquery ui autocomplete)

My problem is, in my autocomplete function I have

```
source: function( request, response ) {
initialize()
}
```

In there, I'm trying to call this function

```
function initialize() {
service.search(request, callback);
}
```

Which works fine... but the problem is... initialize does a call out to the function callback()... so I'm not sure how to listen to see when the callback is done.

So for example, what would I do here:

```
source: function( request, response ) {
// need code here to know when initialize and callback are done and are sending me the list of results from google ?
}
```

I'm just not sure how to wait for google places to get done, before I use $.map from the results to produce the dropdown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timing issues with google apis?  I feel your pain.  But to sidestep your issue and maybe save you some pain, you could use Google's prebuilt solution:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#places_autocomplete

Apologies if you have some reason to not use their API.

Comment: Downvotes on me and the OP with no comments to either. Awesome!

Comment: If it means anything, I truly appreciate your answer :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it only works if you are using a Google map, if you are using Mapbox/leaflet, it doesn't work. 8-(